# CryptDecrypt() Failing to decrypt some blocks C++

Tags: c++, winapi, encryption, cryptoapi

I'm currently working on a simple encryption/decryption system in C++ using the Windows API.

I believe I've been successful at getting `CryptEncrypt()` to work (AES_128) for encrypting a file.
But when I Use `CryptDecrypt()` to decrypt the file, the first 16 bytes are corrupted and then after 4000 bytes (which is the size of the chunks I'm pulling from `ReadFile()` and encrypting) is another chunk of corrupted bytes and so on. If I try to decrypt a file with a total length less than 4000 bytes, the decryption works perfectly.

I'm very confused about why this is happening. There are no errors at all.

Here is a snippet of my code (I have `CryptEncrypt()` and `CryptDecrypt()` right after each other to save me exporting the key and to make the testing faster):

```
DWORD bytesRead;
DWORD bytesWritten;
DWORD pointer = 0;
unsigned int blockSize = 4000;
void *fileBuffer = new unsigned char[4106];
bool EOF = false;
do
{
    SetFilePointer(hFileOrginal,pointer,0,0);
    ReadFile(hFileOrginal,fileBuffer,blockSize,&bytesRead,NULL);
    if(bytesRead<blockSize)
    {
        EOF=true;
    }
    CryptEncrypt(aesKey,NULL,EOF,0,(BYTE *)fileBuffer,&bytesRead,(blockSize+16));
    CryptDecrypt(aesKey,NULL,EOF,0,(BYTE *)fileBuffer,&bytesRead);

    WriteFile(hTempFile,fileBuffer,bytesRead,&bytesWritten,NULL);
    pointer +=bytesRead;
}
while(!EOF);
delete[] fileBuffer;
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions about whats going wrong.

EDIT: On a 4704 bytes file I got the following using breakpoints.

First ReadFile bytesread 4000
First CryptEncrypt bytesRead 4000
First CryptDecrypt bytesRead 4000
Second ReadFile bytesread 704
Second CryptEncrypt bytesread 720
Second CryptDecrupt bytesread 704

Everything seems good with that yet I still get a problem.

I'm using the enhanced crypto api (With verifycontext) with a generated a single AES key with the CRYPT_EXPORTABLE property

Comment: Try adding some tests to ensure that bytesRead is the same before and after the CryptEncrypt and CryptDecrypt pair are called. You also don't need your SetFilePointer and `pointer` code as `ReadFile` will read sequentially anyway.

Comment: Everything seems normal with that. I edited the results into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing any error handling at all.  All of the API functions you are calling have return values and error codes, none of which you are checking.

You are also not managing `bytesRead` correctly.  `CryptEncrypt()` modifies the variable you pass to it, which then affects your call to `CreateDecrypt()`, which also modifies it, and that then affects subsequent calls to `SetFilePointer()`, which you should not be calling in your loop to begin with.  You are not validating that you have as many bytes as you are expecting, or that `bytesRead` ends up back at the original value that `ReadFile()` returned, so you may end up skipping bytes in the source file.

Try something more like this instead:

```
bool ReadFromFile(HANDLE hFile, void *Buffer, DWORD BufSize, DWORD *BytesRead)
{
    if (BytesRead)
        *BytesRead = 0;

    LPBYTE pBuffer = (LPBYTE) Buffer;
    DWORD dwRead;

    while (BufSize > 0)
    {
        if (!ReadFile(hFile, pBuffer, BufSize, &dwRead, NULL))
            return false;

        if (dwRead == 0)
            break;

        pBuffer += dwRead;
        BufSize -= dwRead;

        if (BytesRead)
            *BytesRead += dwRead;
    }

    return true;
}

bool WriteToFile(HANDLE hFile, void *Buffer, DWORD BufSize)
{
    LPBYTE pBuffer = (LPBYTE) Buffer;
    DWORD dwWritten;

    while (BufSize > 0)
    {
        if (!WriteFile(hFile, pBuffer, BufSize, &dwWritten, NULL))
            return false;

        pBuffer += dwWritten;
        BufSize -= dwWritten;
    }

    return true;
}
```

```
DWORD bytesRead;
const UINT blockSize = 4000;
LPBYTE fileBuffer = new BYTE[blockSize+16];
bool EOF;

if (SetFilePointer(hFileOrginal, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN) != 0)
{
    errorCode = GetLastError();
    ...
}
else
{
    do
    {
        if (!ReadFromFile(hFileOrginal, fileBuffer, blockSize, &bytesRead))
        {
            errorCode = GetLastError();
            ...
            break;
        }

        EOF = (bytesRead < blockSize);

        bytesEncrypted = bytesRead;
        if (!CryptEncrypt(aesKey, NULL, EOF, 0, fileBuffer, &bytesEncrypted, blockSize+16))
        {
            errorCode = GetLastError();
            ...
            break;
        }

        bytesDecrypted = bytesEncrypted;
        if (!CryptDecrypt(aesKey, NULL, EOF, 0, fileBuffer, &bytesDecrypted))
        {
            errorCode = GetLastError();
            ...
            break;
        }

        if (!WriteToFile(hTempFile, fileBuffer, bytesDecrypted))
        {
            errorCode = GetLastError();
            ...
            break;
        }

        if (bytesDecrypted != bytesRead)
        {
            ...
            break;
        }
    }
    while (!EOF);
}
delete[] fileBuffer;
```

Comment: I had a look through your code and implemented it. It worked fine right off the bat but I'm encountering the same problem. Your code is much better looking and maintainable than mine though so I'm going to keep it.

Comment: Can you show the code that is initializing `aesKey`? Have you tried using separate key handles for encrypting/decrypting instead of sharing a single handle?

Comment: perfect... like always.